# Problem with Tikzpicture and Adjustbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, adjustbox

I would like to place four `tikzpicture`s on the same horizontal line but I am not able to  set the `tikzpicture`s on the same horizontal line (see the LaTeX code below). 
Using the code reported below, each `tikzpicture` is placed below the previous `tikzpicture` (and this is not what I am searching for).

Is there a way to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\begin{document}



    %   1


\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.10\textwidth}}


  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,    
auto]
    \node (z){0}
child {
    node {a}            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}  

     \end{adjustbox}            


\hfill




                %   2

\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.45\textwidth}}





  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,    
auto]
    \node (z){0}
child {
    node {b}            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}



     \end{adjustbox}            



    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.65\textwidth}}





  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,  
auto]
    \node (z){0}
child {
    node {b}            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}



     \end{adjustbox}    



\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.85\textwidth}}





  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,    
auto]
    \node (z){0}
child {
    node {b}            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}



     \end{adjustbox}    






\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest you remove the `center` environment, as it starts a new paragraph. You'd rather use `\centering`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total width of the four `minipage`s is longer than `\textwidth`; besides, there are blank lines in your code (I don't know wether they are in the actual code or were just result of copy-paste in the question) that shouldn't be there (a blank line ends the paragraph and following material will begin a new paragraph). Adjust the width of the `minipage`s, for example, to `0.25\textwidth` and beware of blank spaces (I also changed the `center` environment to `\centering`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.25\textwidth}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,auto]
\node (z){0}
  child {  node {a} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}%
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.25\textwidth}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,auto]
\node (z){0}
  child {  node {b} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}%            
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.25\textwidth}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,auto]
\node (z){0}
  child {  node {b} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}%    
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,minipage={.25\textwidth}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,thick,auto]
\node (z){0}
  child {  node {b} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}    

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]